# Looking for Journey Builder Pause Clarification

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions, automationstudio, activity

We have some multi-touch journeys in salesforce marketing cloud journey builder with multiple emails and wait time and decision splits in between.

I have discovered a data issue and my concern is  that contacts will fail at the decision split.

I would like to clarify - if I pause any journey and select the following

- Extend Wait by Duration Periods
- Pause expiration After 14 days automatically resume  the journey

**Extend Wait by Duration Periods** - Does this mean if contacts are on any wait step will remain on the wait step and won't move forward at all? and when I resume the journey, will contacts start moving forward right away or later? if later when? Just trying to understand and plan the wait time extension.

**Pause expiration After 14 days automatically resume  the journey** - Is the 14 days just an arbitrary number and if i resume a journey version within 14 days, 14 days doesn't mean any then? I just want to make sure 14 days is not adding 14 days period to any step in the journey canvas.

Answer (score -1):

This is pretty well covered here: [Journey Pause](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_jb_pause.htm&type=5)

> You can extend or not extend the wait time of all Wait by Duration activities on that journey by the duration of the journey’s pause. If you don’t extend the wait time and the wait expires during a pause, the contact is processed after the journey resumes. Your selection for this option applies to all Wait by Duration activities on the paused journey (or all versions of the journey). This configuration option is only available for Wait by Duration activities. The wait time for Wait by Attribute and Wait for Date isn’t extended by default.

> Journeys can be paused for up to 14 days in 1-day increments. Each day is a 24-hour period starting from when the journey is paused. While pausing a journey, you can configure it to resume or stop at the end of the pause duration. You can manually resume a paused journey anytime during the pause duration.